# how to implement foreign key constraint in EF Core modelling classes

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have the following model classes:

```cs
public enum Roster
{
    None,
    One,
    Two,
    Three,
    Four
}

[Index(nameof(UniColumn), IsUnique = true)]
internal class RowRosterEnum
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    [EnumDataType(typeof(Roster))]
    public Roster RosterEnum { get; set; }

    public Roster UniColumn { get; set; }
}

internal class RowRoster
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey(nameof(RowRosterEnum))]
    public Roster RId { get; set; }

    public string? Name { get; set; }

    public RowRosterEnum RowRosterEnum { get; set; }

}
```

when I create migration files, this code is generated:

```cs
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "TableRosterEnum",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    RosterEnum = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
                    UniColumn = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_TableRosterEnum", x => x.RosterEnum);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "TableRoster",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    RId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
                    Name = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_TableRoster", x => x.RId);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_TableRoster_TableRosterEnum_RId",
                        column: x => x.RId,
                        principalTable: "TableRosterEnum",
                        principalColumn: "RosterEnum",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_TableRosterEnum_UniColumn",
                table: "TableRosterEnum",
                column: "UniColumn",
                unique: true);
```

is it possible to modify model classes, so the foreign key comes from UniColumn and not from RosterEnum, basically I want migration code to be generated like this:

```cs
principalColumn: "UniColumn",
```

I want RosterEnum to remain the primary key.

Answer (score 0):

You could try define relationship in DbContext class like below.

```
    public class RowRoster
    {
        [Key]
        public Roster RId { get; set; }

        public string? Name { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey(nameof(RowRosterEnum))]
        public Roster UniColumn { get; set; }
        public RowRosterEnum RowRosterEnum { get; set; }

    }
```

```
   public class RowRosterEnum
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        [EnumDataType(typeof(Roster))]
        public Roster RosterEnum { get; set; }

        public Roster UniColumn { get; set; }

        public RowRoster RowRoster { get; set; }
    }
```

Context

```
    public class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseMySql("server=192.168.2.68;database=WA119;user=mysql1;password=Q!q11111", new MySqlServerVersion(new Version()));
        }

        public DbSet<RowRosterEnum> TableRosterEnum { get; set; }
        public DbSet<RowRoster> TableRoster { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<RowRoster>()
                .HasOne(x => x.RowRosterEnum)
                .WithOne(x => x.RowRoster)
                .HasPrincipalKey<RowRosterEnum>(x => x.UniColumn);               
        }
    }
```

Test
[image]

Comment: that creates new column RowRosterEnumUniColumn which I don't need, and it makes it a foreign key which I don't need either. I need RId to be the primary key with foreign key constraint. Probably I should ask a simpler question - how to write modelling classes (and possible DbContext overrides) to have migration generate an equivalent of this:
CREATE TABLE ParentTable (
    ParentID INT PRIMARY KEY,
 UniColumn INT UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE ChildTable (
    ChildID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    FOREIGN KEY (ChildID) REFERENCES ParentTable(UniColumn)
);